# groupdate gem not included in Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile, rails-console

I have

> gem 'groupdate'

in my Gemfile in my Rails project. I run bundle and then open bin/rails c to test the methods out yet I still get the error:

> [4] pry(main)> users.group_by_day { |u| u.created_at }
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `group_by_day' for #>>><User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007faee79ca818>
>   from /Users/Jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in`method_missing'

I've ran bundle update and whatnot and I'm unsure what the issue could be

Comment: restart your server and then tell me

Comment: Exit `rails c` and then try using code in console again.

Comment: Are you running console by `bundle exec rails c`?

Comment: It was bundle exec rails c that did it! Why was that different from simply running bin/rails c in the terminal?